# Как спрятать API_KEY?

Tags: javascript, api

Немогу спрятать ключ api которий получил в openweather, как ето сделать не используя node?
Код JS:

```
const key = "мой ключ"

const target = document.querySelector(".weather__content--city")
const temp = document.querySelector(".weather__content--temp")
const icon = document.querySelector(".weather__content--icon")
const description = document.querySelector(".weather__content--description")
const humidity = document.querySelector(".weather__content--humidity")
const wind = document.querySelector(".weather__content--wind")

const input = document.querySelector(".weather__search--input")
const btn = document.querySelector(".weather__search--btn")

// get weather
function getWeather(city="Lviv") {
  fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=metric&appid=" + key)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json()
    }).then(data => {
      showWeather(data)
    })
}

// show weather data
function showWeather(data) {
  const dName = data.name
  const dIcon = data.weather[0].icon
  const dDescription = data.weather[0].description
  const dTemp = data.main.temp
  const dHumidity = data.main.humidity
  const dWind = data.wind.speed
  
  target.innerHTML = dName
  temp.innerHTML = Math.floor(dTemp) + "°C"
  icon.src = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + dIcon + ".png"
  description.innerHTML = dDescription
  humidity.innerHTML = "Humidity: " + dHumidity + "%"
  wind.innerHTML = "Wind speed: " + dWind + " km/h"
}

// search city 
function searchCity() {
  const value = input.value
  getWeather(value)
}

// keyup event
input.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    searchCity()
  }
})

// click event
btn.addEventListener("click", searchCity)

getWeather()
```

Comment: как  бы Вы его не прятали, в конце концов Вам нужно будет его декриптовать и передать в запрос к openweather.

Comment: Обычно при использовании таких штук можно настроить домены, с которых `api-ключ` будет работать

Comment: Можете подсказать как сделать?

Comment: Если это вопрос ко мне - нет, с `openweather` не работал. Поищите в админке `openweather`. Могу сказать, что гуглокарты, гуглокапча, яндекс-карты такую настройку для API имеют.